# Android Shutdown Event

Tags: android

Is it possible to cancel a shutdown event in Android? Basically if the the user tries to shutdown the phone, an Android app that is running can cancel the shutdown event. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for and respond to the `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` Intent, but canceling the event is not possible. You might be able to delay shutdown by registering a "shutdown hook" somewhere within your application's lifecycle and doing something blocking. Something like:

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something at least useful

            // and not this
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000); // please don't do this... think of the unicorns
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I thought it would be possible to cancel the event, because we are developing a tracking application using the phone's GPS, and we would like that the user would not be able to shutdown the phone.

Comment: I'd suggest reevaluating your app's design, as even if you could block a user-initiated shutdown, you're just not going to be able to prevent the battery from dying or the user from pulling out the battery to force a shutdown.

Comment: I'd suggest requiring the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and restart your tracker when the phone is restarted. It's not nice to prevent the user from rebooting their device.